# Take out duplicates from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I need some help with my query...I wan't to get the tradeId:s that are duplicates and are missing a LegId. Can you please help me?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
<value>
    <TradeId>928</TradeId>
    <LegId>1</LegId>
</value>
<value>
    <TradeId>928</TradeId>
    <LegId>2</LegId>
</value>
<value>
    <TradeId>928</TradeId>
    //MISSING LEGID HERE
</value>
<value>
    <TradeId>929</TradeId>
    <LegId>1</LegId>
</value>
<value>
    <TradeId>929</TradeId>
    <LegId>2</LegId>
</value>
<value>
    <TradeId>930</TradeId>
    <LegId>2</LegId>
</value>
</data>
```

Im declaring this XML to a variable and then filling a #temptable with the result:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') AS strTradeId
        ,e.value('LegId[1]','int') AS LegId
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value') AS elements(e)
    WHERE   1 = 1
) AS t



SELECT   *
FROM    #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore AS t
```

This gives me following output:
[image: output]

The only row I wan't in this case is number 3, the one marked in yellow (I only need the TradeId column). This query:

```
SELECT t.strTradeId
INTO #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') AS strTradeId
        ,e.value('LegId[1]','int') AS LegId
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value') AS elements(e)
) AS t
WHERE   1 = 1
--AND       t.LegId IS NULL
GROUP BY  t.strTradeId
HAVING COUNT(t.strTradeId) > 1


SELECT   *
FROM    #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore AS t
```

And that leaves me with two rows with 928 and 929, but I can't get the one were LegId IS NULL...

Requested output from this case: one with TradeId 928.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: did you try `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way, modify xpath for the `FROM` clause to select only `<value>`s not having child `<LegId>` :

```
data/value[not(LegId)]
```

See the xpath in action :

```
SELECT *
INTO #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') AS strTradeId
        ,e.value('LegId[1]','int') AS LegId
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value[not(LegId)]') AS elements(e)
    WHERE   1 = 1
) AS t

SELECT   *
FROM    #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore AS t
```

Output :

[image]

**Update :**

I missed the requirement to check for duplicates before. So here is a different way to achieve the same, but with addition of duplicates checking :

```
SELECT *
INTO #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') AS strTradeId
        ,e.value('LegId[1]','int') AS LegId
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value') AS elements(e)
    WHERE   1 = 1
) AS t

SELECT   t.strTradeId
FROM    #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore AS t
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 'count', strTradeId
            FROM #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
            GROUP BY strTradeId
        ) As t2 on t2.strTradeId = t.strTradeId
WHERE LegId IS NULL AND t2.count > 1
```

Output :

[image]

**Update 2:**

```
;with T as (
    SELECT 
         e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') AS strTradeId
        ,e.value('LegId[1]','int') AS LegId
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value') AS elements(e)
)
SELECT *
INTO #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
FROM
(
    SELECT T.strTradeId
    FROM T
    GROUP BY T.strTradeId
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND COUNT(*)>COUNT(T.LegId)
) AS t

SELECT * FROM #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to move the duplicate check to the insert of #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore ?

Comment: @krillezzz as far as I can see, not possible using the same approach. counting all records (with `GROUP BY`) while filtering for null only records in one go is not an easy task, fortunately Roman Pekar came up with a clever approach (+1 for him) : `count(*) > count(c.LegId)`. Check **update 2**.

Comment: sorry, but I don't think copying code from my answer is fair. the cte version is completely copied from my answer.

Comment: @RomanPekar what a shame, really sorry for the inconvenience. Actually, I spent a little while to reread about CTE (after got stucked trying to achieve the same without CTE), and played around with code examples I found. One of them is this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER) (where I took the `T` cte table name), and also the code in your answer. I didn't aware that in the end I posted the one containing copy of your version instead of mine/OP's (the one using `AS elements(e)` instead of `AS e(e)`.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this query to get duplicates with nulls:

```
;with cte_splitted as (
    select
        e.e.value('TradeId[1]','varchar(50)') as strTradeId,
        e.e.value('LegId[1]','int') as LegId
    from @xmlData.nodes('data/value') as e(e)
)
select
    c.strTradeId
into #tradeIdDuplicatesToIgnore
from cte_splitted as c
group by
    c.strTradeId
having
    count(*) > count(c.LegId) and -- count of all records <> count of not null records
    count(*) > 1 -- there're more than 1 record
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4131)</kbd>**